# Meaning of the phrase "be predicated of"

Tags: meaning

Here is the sentence it was used in: "It must simply be that the quantity may be trully predicated of the object." What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For X **to be predicated of** {something} is [philosophy and philosophy-of-language jargon](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22predicated%20of%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) which means  that the assertion embodied by X is true with relation to the {something}.

> It can be predicated of the giraffe that it has a long neck.

One of the giraffe's inherent attributes is that it has a long neck.

It can be **said of** the giraffe that it has a long neck.

Not to be confused with **predicated on**.

> Democracy is predicated on the idea that peoples are able to govern
>   themselves.

which means "founded on, based on".

Answer (score 0):

Here meaning of predicated can be: base of, dependent on.

So here: the quantity is the factor on which the object is dependent.